# Should I use ActionBarSherlock for Android 4.0+ apps?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

My app will only run on Android 4.0/API 14 or later (i.e. minSdkVersion="14", targetSdkVersion="17").

Is there any advantage to using ActionBarSherlock in this scenario?

Comment: The library will automatically use the native action bar when appropriate, so there is no need using it, unless you just want to

Comment: The ActionBarSherlock is only designed for API Levels below 11

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Is there any advantage to using ActionBarSherlock in this scenario?

As the developer of ActionBarSherlock I can only tell you one thing...

## NOPE! :)

The whole point of the library was that someday it can just go away. You can read more about this in [a blog post I wrote](http://jakewharton.com/deprecated-from-inception/) called "Deprecated from Inception".

Comment: Ah, the wonders of StackOverflow- asking a question and the creator of the Project answering it himself ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  But even bigger thanks for creating something that you knew would eventually be deprecated!!!

Comment: @Jake CAN we use ActionBarSherlock for 4.0+ apps? That is to say, if I am already using ActionBarSherlock in a pre-ICS app, and I change the minSDK to 14+ would you recommend changing to the native ActionBar? Is it worth the trouble of changing the code?

Comment: @MattRobertson Yes, you should switch to native only. This should amount to: getSupportActionBar() -> getActionBar(), com.actionbarsherlock.* imports -> android.* imports, Theme.Sherlock.* -> Theme.Holo.*.  And that's it!