# Is it worth it to use actionbarsherlock if I'm targeting 4.0+?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

With the assumption that I will never not target less than 4.0, should I include and use the actionbarsherlock?

Is there something I am missing, some reason to use it, or some reason I might regret my decision in the future?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776456/should-i-use-actionbarsherlock-for-android-4-0-apps/15776594#15776594

Comment: Why Don't you simply use Actiobar as you are targetting 4+

Comment: Thanks mr_archano. I searched but that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The whole vision behind actionbarsherlock is to provide backward compatibility for the ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

From the website of [ActionBarSharlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

> ActionBarSherlock is an extension of the support library designed to
>   facilitate the use of the action bar design pattern across all
>   versions of Android with a single API.
>
> The library will automatically use the native action bar when
>   appropriate or will automatically wrap a custom implementation around
>   your layouts. This allows you to easily develop an application with an
>   action bar for every version of Android from 2.x and up.

That clearly says that It is just a wrapper which uses the android actionbar for the supported api and uses its own implementation in lower api for compatibility issue.

But as you are gonna use api level 4 or higher , there The android ActionBar is available. So Using ActionBarSharlock will be only an overhead for you